# how to check if a blockhash has expired using @solana/web3.js?

Tags: transactions

I'm using `getLatestBlockhash()` to pass into a transaction.

```
const { blockhash } = await connection.getLatestBlockhash("finalized");
```

However, I want to invalidate the transaction on my backend if a block has passed and the user has not approved the transaction. How I would check if a block has expired using `@solana/web3.js`?

Comment: can you elaborate what you mean by "if a block has passed", as well as your motivation for invalidation?

Comment: i'm creating a partially signed transaction on my backend, saving the transaction referrence in a database. sending the transaction to the front end and asking the user to sign it. there's a cron job on my backend that uses ```findReferrence()``` to check if a transaction is successful, but i also want to check if a block has passed before a user is able to sign/the user has left the site and the transaction will never be completed so i want to invalidate the transaction

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to "invalidate" a transaction that has been fully signed and broadcast, it can only be allowed to expire.

The reply of `getLatestBlockhash` also has a `lastValidBlockheight` field.  `getEpochInfo` can be polled until the value in its `blockHeight` field exceeds the blockhash's last valid height. The cookbook has a pretty good explainer on the [lifetime of transactions](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the web3 method [`simulateTransaction`](https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/classes/Connection.html#simulateTransaction). If the blockhash has expired then this method returns an error indicating that the blockhash has expired.

The blockhash is valid if it is within the last 150 blocks.

Do note though that `sendTransaction` will also check that the blockhash is valid for you, so long as the you do not skip the preflight checks, `skipPreflight: false`, which is one of the `sendOptions` in the `sendTransaction` method. More on that from the cookbook [here](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#the-cost-of-skipping-preflight)

The solana cookbook also goes into more detail here on [keeping the transaction fresh](https://solanacookbook.com/guides/retrying-transactions.html#when-to-re-sign-transactions). It references an RPC method that isn't yet available on the web3 library specifically for the purpose of checking a blockhash is still valid, called [isBlockhashValid](https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api#isblockhashvalid).

Comment: use of `isBlockhashValid` should be discouraged as it can return false in situations other than when the blockhash has expired

Comment: Probably should update the solana cookbook then